# HTTP Repository(ies) for RedHat EL

Tags: redhat, repository

FTP is completely disabled on our network due to security. No inbound or outbound ftp is allowed.

I just created a new install of RHEL on one of our systems, and the only two repositories (official) mentioned are both are ftp. Does anyone know if there is an official http based repository out there, and if so, the address of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me - you simply have to replace the ftp:// with http:// in the baseurl:

```
http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/
```